# Replicating a Neural Network Paper

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I have a pretty good understanding of basic concepts in neural networks. I'm looking to replicate the findings of a paper to get a better understanding of some more advanced concepts. I'm open to anything from momentum, deep networks, RNNs, etc.

Any suggestions on which papers would be best for this, or even for reading. Google wasn't all that helpful.

Bonus points for open datasets and free publications.

Comment: I've found this blog to be very useful: http://colah.github.io/.

Answer (score 3):

http://gitxiv.com/ is pretty dedicated to hosting open papers, their code and occasionally a virtual environment hosted online with the required dependencies.

There's also assignments hosted online by Stanford for courses in [convolutional neural networks for image recognition](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/) and [recurrent neural networks for natural language processing](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/).